# SQL: Finding all employees hired on a specific day of the week

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max

I have trouble finding all employees, that are hired on a day of the week(Monday,Tuesday etc.) that has the highest hiring rate.

For exmaple: if Monday is the day that has the highest hiring count, I want to display all employees that are hired on that day of the week.

I found which days has the highest hiring count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
HAVING COUNT (*)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'));
```

But I can't display all employees hired on that days. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
select * from employees
where to_char(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') in

SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
HAVING COUNT (*)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'));
```

Comment: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: You must have a tie or ties for max hire date.

Comment: if you just run the second part:                                                              SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
HAVING COUNT (*)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'));        what do you get?

Comment: The second part runs OK, as I mentioned above. Just don't know how to combine it so it shows all employees hired on that "max hiring" day

Comment: but what is the actual output from that select? do you get a single row?

Comment: I'm getting as result : Saturday
                                  Friday ... so 2 days that have the same max hiring rate.

Comment: so you have two days that have a maximum count.  Do you care which one you use, do you want to list both of them?  seems odd that the maximum hire occurs on a Saturday

Comment: so in the top select   select * from employees
where to_char(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') =
  change the = to in

Comment: Well I guess both of them, since my task is to display all employees hired on max hiring day. And ye it's odd, but its some basic Oracle tables, not created by me.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, and it worked like a charm. Tanks again for your time!!

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote the answer, don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle syntax, but join EMPLOYEES on that query. Would resemble something like:

```
SELECT  e.*
FROM EMPLOYEES e
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT <employee id>, TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY') DAY
    FROM EMPLOYEES
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
    HAVING COUNT (*)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(*))FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY'))) AS empdays
    ON TO_CHAR(e.HIRE_DATE, 'DAY') = empdays.DAY;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, helped me a lot and it works OK now ! Thank you for your time.